# Is it possible to create a random list of integers inside a c# constructor?

Tags: c#, .net, random

I have created a constructor, originally it was okay to create some hard coded values. Now the time has come where I need to random create values. Is it possible to do so within a constructor. For example I have the following:

```
private Random _random;

public GuessingGame()
{
    this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
    this.Target = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    this._random = new Random();
}

public List<int> Target { get; set; }
public List<Guess> Guesses { get; set; }
```

I have tried creating a `new Random()` and then doing then tried assigning this, but it didn't work. What would be the best way to create random integers within my constructor?

Comment: What didn't work? Any exceptions?

Comment: Just call _random.Next in a loop the number of times you want and add the value to the list

Comment: Possibly more compact way to create list of 3 random values `Target = Enumerable.Repeat(1, 3).Select(i => _random.Next()).ToList()`

Answer (score 1):

```
public GuessingGame()
{
    this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
    this._random = new Random();
    this.Target = new List<int>();

    int randomCount = 3; // how many randoms
    int rndMin = 1; // min value of random
    int rndMax = 10; // max value of random


    for (int i = 0; i < randomCount; i++)
      this.Target.Add(this._random.Next(rndMin, rndMax));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The LINQ version:

```
public GuessingGame() {
    _random = new Random();
    Target = Enumerable
                 .Repeat(0, how_many_items)
                 .Select(x => _random.Next(max_random_number_value))
                 .ToList();
    // ..the rest..
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this line of code

```
for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
 this.Target.Add(this._random.Next(0,10));
}
```

fills Target list with 10 random numbers between 0 and 9

```
private Random _random;

public GuessingGame()
{
    this.Guesses = new List<Guess>();
    this.Target = new List<int>() { 1, 2, 3 };
    this._random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);  
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
     this.Target.Add(this._random.Next(0,10));
    }


}

public List<int> Target { get; set; }
public List<Guess> Guesses { get; set; }
```